# AJAX Call not hitting Controller Method - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I've tries setting breakpoints at the Controller method. But it does not stop there. The alerts "clicked" and the next one work perfectly fine. But the controller method is not called. Any help is appreciated. Here's my ajax call and my controller method.

```
var Url = "@Url.Action("~/Home/Get_Location")";

$("#gotoloc").click(function() {
  alert("clicked");
  alert(lat +" "+ lon);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: Url,
    data: { 
      latitude: lat, 
      longitude: lon    
    },
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      alert("Hello:" + response)
    },
    failure: function(response) {
      alert(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function(response) {
      alert(response.responseText);
    }
  });
  alert("ignored");
});
```

```csharp
public JsonResult Get_Location(double latitude,double longitude)
{
  string loc = latitude + "/" + longitude;
  return Json(loc, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: Do any of the other `alert()` calls fire? I'd expect the `error` one to at least. Check the console for errors

Comment: open your console and check for any errors. Also check your network tab

Comment: It says it cannot find the function. I have changed the Url content as Shyju suggested, But now, its throwing an alert saying 'Invalid Json Primitive latitude'.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `Url.Action` method incorrectly.

Try this

```
var Url = "@Url.Action("Get_Location","Home")";
```

The above overload takes the action method name as first parameter and controller names as second parameter

Also, i see you are passing incorrect contentType request header. contentType headers tells the server what is the type of data the client is sending. Your current code says you are sending json data. But you have 2 parameters in your action method and the json serializer will fail to properly map the posted data to it, hence you will be getting a 500 response from the server.

This should work, assuming there are no other js errors in your page

```
var url = "@Url.Action("Get_Location","Home")";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: { latitude: 44, longitude: 55 },
    success: function (response) {
        console.log("Hello:" + response);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        console.log(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Well spotted, although I suspect this isn't the only issue if no other `alert()` calls are firing